# IOS 6 with weird resizing

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autoresize, ios6

I've a UIView that contains a UIScrollView.
Both of them, has the exactly size of 768x1004 pixels, to fit correctly on the iPad screen.

When the orientation of the iPad changes to landscape mode, the autoresize of the views changes to 1044x728 pixels, not being the correct ratio and making weird behaviors.

That only occurs when I'm working in iOS 6, and when the iPad starts on landscape mode.

In old versions there's never a problem and when de iPad starts on portrait mode, the functionalities are working well.

To make it working ok, I must change the initial sizes to 748x1044, but then in all other cases the application has not the correct sizes.

My conclusion is that there is some kind of mechanism or bug maybe, that has appeared in iOS 6, when the iPad launches in landscape mode, that changes the sizes you have previously configured on the xib.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are your springs and struts configured?

Comment: Sorry, I'm little bit noob. Are you talking about autoresizingMask?

Comment: In that case, all the filters are activated, resize width and height, and to all directions, I want to expand the UIView at maximum.

Comment: have you set window.rootViewController or instead added the view as a subview to the window? (hint: use the first)

Comment: It's true that if I call the ViewController as a Modal view, it works properly!

Answer (score 3):

I can't give the exact code to fix your problem. A way I use to debug sizing issue like these are to log out the frame of my outermost view when important things happen.

e.g.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
 //.. etc
 NSLog(@"viewDidLoad: %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(self.view.frame) );
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
 //.. etc
 NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews: %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(self.view.frame) );
}

 - (void) viewDidAppear {
 //.. etc
 NSLog(@"viewDidAppear: %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(self.view.frame) );
}
```

Normally by watching the log you can see what's going wrong and where.

Comment: I've tried what are you suggesting, and it confirms my thoughts.
On portrait mode:
viewDidLoad: {
    Height = 400;
    Width = 600;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
And after re-orientation:
viewDidLayoutSubviews: {
    **Height = 144;**
    **Width = 856;**
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}

That works fine, but if it launches on landscape orientation:
viewDidLoad: {
    Height = 400;
    Width = 600;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
viewDidLayoutSubviews: {
    **Height = 124;**
    **Width = 876;**
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
**The height is 20 pixels less than usual, and the width is 20 pixels more...**